# Obtener Maximo y minimo de una consulta Calculada SQL (2 columnas). Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Este query es la parte final de un store procedure que logra mostrarme los resultados de esta manera:

```
final_comparativo as (
                    select s.CeEmplazamiento, avg(s.Totales) TotalGeneral , s2.TotGral, @Mes as Mes
                    from tmpSemanas s
                        cross join ( select avg(Totales) TotGral from tmpSemanas s2 where Totales >0) s2
                    group by s.CeEmplazamiento , s2.TotGral
            union all
                    select ss.CeEmplazamiento, avg(ss.Totales) TotalGeneral , ss2.TotGral, @Mes_comparar as Mes
                    from tmpSemanas_comparar ss
                        cross join ( select avg(Totales) TotGral from tmpSemanas_comparar ss2 where Totales >0) ss2
                    group by ss.CeEmplazamiento , ss2.TotGral
        ), maximo_minimo as (
            select CeEmplazamiento,
                max(case when Mes  = @Mes then TotalGeneral else 0 end) as Mes_actual,
                max(case when Mes  = @Mes_comparar then TotalGeneral else 0 end) as Mes_comparar
            from final_comparativo
            where TotalGeneral <> 0
            group by CeEmplazamiento    
            )

            select * from maximo_minimo
            drop table #tmpDatos
end
```

Esta es la tabla resultado actualmente:

```
CeEmplazamiento Mes_actual  Mes_comparar
Celaya          76.500000   75.600000
Coecillo        79.000000   79.800000
Irapuato        77.500000   75.400000
León Sur        85.750000   87.600000
Oriente León    86.250000   85.200000
```

El store procedure te pide 2 argumentos que corresponden a mes_actual (mes de origen) mes_comparar(contra que mes deseas comparar el mes_actual) por lo tanto ya es un calculo final. Pero mi problema radica en lo siguiente, quisiera que de este tabla me tome el máximo y minimo del mes_actual y de igual forma para la columna "Mes_comparar", espero haberme explicado. De manera mas resumida, quisiera que quedara de esta manera.

```
CeEmplazamiento      Mes_Actual  Mes_comparar
Oriente León         86.250000   NULL
Celaya               76.500000   NULL
León Sur                 NULL    87.600000
Irapuato                 NULL    75.400000
```

Por lo que ustedes pueden notar, no es la misma cantidad para todos los CeEmplazamiento, aquellos que no se encuentran en el Mes_actual, no se muestran pero se toman en cuenta para un gráfico que se esta haciendo. Es una tabla cruzada, yo lo estoy intetando con un case, pero no me permite mostrar los nulos. Espero y me puedan ayudar. Gracias.

Comment: creo que tu resultado mostrado esta mal.. oriente leon tiene el maximo para el mes actual.. o estoy entendiendo mal lo que queres hacer...

Comment: Una disculpa, lo estoy corrigiendo, es Verdad.

Comment: ok, ya te tengo una solucion, dame unos minutos que te la refino...

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos

Answer (score 1):

OK, esto esta en Oracle, no en SQL server, pq no esta andando mi version local no se porque, asi que despues te lo actualizo, pero una posible solucion seria:

```
select ceemplazamiento , max(t_mes_actual), max(t_mes_comparar)
from(

select *
from(
select ceemplazamiento,
max(mes_actual) t_mes_actual,
null t_mes_comparar
from
temp
group by ceemplazamiento
order by max(mes_actual) desc)
where rownum < 2

union

select *
from(
select ceemplazamiento,
min(mes_actual) t_mes_actual,
null t_mes_comparar
from
temp
group by ceemplazamiento
order by min(mes_actual) asc)
where rownum < 2

union

select *
from(
select ceemplazamiento,
null t_mes_actual,
max(mes_comparar) t_mes_comparar
from
temp
group by ceemplazamiento
order by max(mes_comparar) desc)
where rownum < 2

union

select *
from(
select ceemplazamiento,
null t_mes_actual,
min(mes_comparar) t_mes_comparar
from
temp
group by ceemplazamiento
order by min(mes_comparar) asc)
where rownum < 2
)
group by ceemplazamiento
```

en sqlserver en lugar de usar rownum usas top, el resto deberia andar igual. fijate si con esto ya encuentras una forma de resolver el problema.

Comment: Lo estoy verificando, pero, si efectivamente tienes razón esto es Oracle, lo estoy adaptando a SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

Otra solución con Outer Joins podria ser esta:
(Nota: Si hay mas de un emplazamiento con valores iguales al máximo/mínimo, también debería funcionar)

```
    select #tmpDatos.CeEmplazamiento, mmActual.MinMax as Mes_Actual,                 
    mmCompara.MinMax as Mes_Compara
    from
    #tmpDatos 
    left outer join
    (select  min(mes_actual) as MinMax from #tmpDatos
     union
     select max(mes_actual) from #tmpDatos
    ) mmActual
    on #tmpDatos.Mes_Actual = mmActual.MinMax
    left outer join
    (select  min(Mes_comparar) as MinMax from #tmpDatos
     union
     select max(Mes_comparar) from #tmpDatos) mmCompara
    on #tmpDatos.Mes_Comparar= mmCompara.MinMax
    order by ceEmplazamiento
```

Comment: Tu solución es buena, aunque con el Mes_actual te muestra mas información de la que debería. Es una buena forma.de hacerlo.